# If I have multiple apps installed in a single iOS device, can I send a single non-duplicate notification for all of them?

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have a requirement of sending notifications to devices which have my apps installed.

I sometimes need to send a notification, for all of my apps. but no single device must show the notification twice.

I want the user see the notification even if the app is not running.

Can I use Apple push notification services to send just one notification for a single device regardless of how many of my apps are installed in the device?
If not what other solutions can I use?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible within APNS, this is something you will have to manage on the server side. compare APNS tokens per app and get a list of unique ones. Then send it to one of the apps per client.

Comment: I simply want it to be possible, no problem with handling it on the provider side. tokens are unique per app, not per device. how can I handle it?